# React menu input:checked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm working with a burger-menu in React, but there's something wrong, but I don't really know why. 
I just have an element with:checked if that is checked than my sidebar get the 60% width, but that doesn't work.

style.css

```
.menu-small {
    width: 0;
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9999999;
    display: block;
}

.menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-small {
    width: 60% !important;
    background: white;
}
```

And I have a burgerMenu Component

```
const burgerMenu = () => {
  return (
    <div className={'burger-icon'}>
        <input type={'checkbox'} className={'menu-btn'} id={'menu-btn'}/>
        <label className="menu-icon" htmlFor="menu-btn"><span className="navicon"/></label>
    </div>
  )
};
```

And at last I've got my Header.js

```
<div className={'container'}>
   {tabletMobileDevice && <>
                <div className={'float-right links menu-small'}>
                    <Link to="/" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Home</Link>
                    <div className={'dropdown'}>
                        <Link to="/shopware/" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Shopware</Link>
                        <div className={'dropdown-content'}>
                            <Link to="/shopware/introductie-shopware-6" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Introductie
                                van Shopware 6</Link>
                            <Link to="/shopware/shopware-iconen" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Shopware
                                Iconen</Link>
                            <Link to="/shopware/veelgestelde-vragen" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Veelgestelde
                                vragen</Link>
                            <Link to="/shopware/plugin-van-de-maand" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Plugin
                                van de maand</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={'dropdown'}>
                        <Link to="/ontwikkeling/" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Ontwikkeling</Link>
                        <div className={'dropdown-content'}>
                            <Link to="/ontwikkeling/api-koppeling" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>API
                                Koppeling</Link>
                            <div className={'sub-dropdown'}>
                                <Link to="/ontwikkeling/plugins" className={'link submenu-plugins'}
                                      activeClassName={'active'} style={{
                                    display: 'inline-block'
                                }}>Plugins</Link>
                                <div className={'sub-dropdown-content'}>
                                    <Link to="/ontwikkeling/plugins/advanced-sidebar-menu/" className={'link'}
                                          activeClassName={'active'}>Advanced sidebar menu</Link>
                                    <Link to="/ontwikkeling/plugins/listing-banner/" className={'link'}
                                          activeClassName={'active'}>Listing Banner</Link>
                                    <Link to="/ontwikkeling/plugins/image-carousel/" className={'link'}
                                          activeClassName={'active'}>Image Carousel</Link>
                                    <Link to="/ontwikkeling/plugins/jupa-koppeling/" className={'link'}
                                          activeClassName={'active'}>Jupa Koppeling</Link>
                                    <Link to="/ontwikkeling/plugins/topbar-dropdown-usp/" className={'link'}
                                          activeClassName={'active'}>Topbar Dropdown USP</Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <Link to="/ontwikkeling/thema" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Thema</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={'dropdown'}>
                        <Link to="/contact/" className={'link'} activeClassName={"active"}>Contact</Link>
                        <div className={'dropdown-content'}>
                            <Link to="/contact/support/" className={'link'} activeClassName={'active'}>Support</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>}
            <Button />
        </div>
```

Does someone know the problem?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You are using [Subsequent-sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators) in your css, but `.menu-small` is not inside `.burger-icon` parent, hence your code doesn't work

Comment: @MrT so... I just need to do .menu-btn:checked .menu-small instead of using .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-small

Comment: Not really. I don't see where do you use `burgerMenu` component, but it sounds to me like you will need to add additional css class to `.menu-small` on checked changed event in react.

Comment: @MrT my <Button/> component is the <burgerMenu /> component I've import the file and with a parameter of <button>